# Extract key data from url based txt file

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a bit of code that analyses the text file at this link [weather report](http://tgftp.nws.noaa.gov/data/observations/metar/decoded/EGHI.TXT) and then finds the line in the file and reads the Celsius value of temperature and returns it. 
The reading for temperature is not always on the same line but it always has the same format on the line.

After doing some reading here on stack overflow I used the re library and an online regex calculator to get some code going for me. This is what I have so far:

```
import urllib
import re

def noaa_string():
  url = "http://tgftp.nws.noaa.gov/data/observations/metar/decoded/EGHI.TXT"
  noaa_data_string = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
  return noaa_data_string.decode("utf-8")


def noaa_temperature(s):
  """takes a string s as returned from noaa_string() as the input argument,
  extracts the temperature in degree Celsius from the string, and returns
  this temperature as an integer number"""
  regex = r"\Temperature........(\d*)"
  matches = re.finditer(regex, noaa_string())

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    matchNum = matchNum + 1
    match = match.group()
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        group = match.group(groupNum)
        print(group)
```

I am getting this error:

```
File "E:/Google Drive/python_files/untitled0.py", line 26, in <module>
for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this error/ an easier way to do what I am trying to do? I feel like I am over complicating things a bit...

Comment: is your for loop suppose to be in the same function for `noaa_temperature`?

Comment: `match = match.group()`: you destroy the match object and replace it by a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said

> ... temperature is not always on the same line but it always has the same format on the line.

So, you don't need the complexity of a regex to solve this issue.

```
import urllib.request

def noaa_string():
    request = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().split(b'\n')
    for row in request:
        if row.startswith(b'Temperature'):
            return row

def noaa_temperature(s):
    return s[s.find(b'(')+1: s.find(b')')]
```

**Edit**

If you want to return the value as an [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) or [`float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float), just convert it using the correspondent functions.

```
int(s[s.find(b'(')+1: s.find(b')')])
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought I might have over complicated it! The value I get returned from that code is b ' 12 C ' how can I return just the integer?